# I want to apply animation on UIImageView(Created through UIBuilder)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have added a UIView, On that UIImageView using UIBuider,
Now I want to apply animation on that imageView, so I'v taken an array of images & adding that 
array to imageView through this code

```
 NSArray *animationArray=[[NSArray alloc]init];
        animationArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit4.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit5.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit6.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit7.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit8.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit9.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit10.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit11.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit12.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"rabbit13.png"], nil];



        tempImageView.animationImages=animationArray;
        tempImageView.animationDuration=2;
        tempImageView.animationRepeatCount=0;
        [tempImageView startAnimating];
```

tempImageView is created using UIBuider
But it is not woking, isn't showing anything.

Comment: are you sure that the IBOutlet for tempImageView is connected in xib

Comment: I'v added UIImageView using UIBuider & doing some code, does anyone think that, is it wrong??

Comment: What's this UIBuilder you keep asking about?

Comment: User Interface Builder, you should estimate it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to a bug in the story board auto layout..i found the same no result..

Try it via code this works..

```
mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    NSArray *animationArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    animationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"], nil]; //add your images here

    [mainImageView  setFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];
    mainImageView.animationImages = animationArray; //mainImageView is   imageview
    mainImageView.animationDuration = 2;
    mainImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [mainImageView startAnimating];


      [self.view addSubview:mainImageView];
```